# matplotlib figure image saved without figure title and axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The following code gives the figure like the image below.

```
plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax = sns.barplot(x=contr, y=X.columns)
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
plt.title('Contribution')

plt.savefig('result_image.png')
plt.show()
```

[What I can see in the jupyter notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HT9Z.png)

However, the saved image ('result_image.png') has no titles or axis, but literally just figure box itself like the picture below

[the real image file is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uch8B.png)

What I wanted is the plt image with title and axis.

=====

**EDIT**

The real problem was not the crop of the figure,
but the figure background being transparent.
(I didn't notice because the background of my photo application was dark)

I solved the problem with the code below.

```
plt.savefig('result_image.png', facecolor='white')
```

Comment: it does have title and axis but in a transparent background, so it's barely visible against a dark background. Do you have your OS configured in dark mode?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Ohhhh I see I didn't noticed because of the dark background. Now I got to know what's the exact problem : to make the figure background not transparent

Comment: could you try `savefig('result_image.png', transparent=False)` ? Otherwise you could try saving in `jpg` format

Comment: Actually I solved the problem with `plt.savefig('result_image.png', facecolor='white')` ! Your code also worked too! Really Thanks! :D

Comment: you can write an answer to your own question if that solved the problem for you. I'd edit the question to include the images instead of links, so the question doesn't depend on external links that might break over time.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was not the crop of the figure, but the figure background being transparent.
(I didn't notice because the background of my photo application was dark)

I solved the problem with the codes below.

```
plt.savefig('result_image.png', facecolor='white')
```

or

```
plt.savefig('result_image.jpg')
```